# JavaScript parse and compare time

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime

I want to check whether a store is open or closed based on the current time.

There are open and close times (format - 09:00:00.000)
And also I'm getting the current time (format - 2021-05-20T22:45:11.000Z)

so, I want to check whether the current time is in between the open time and the close time.

I'm having trouble formatting both times into one format and compare.

This is how I'm getting the current time with the time zone.

```
let curent_date = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {
  timeZone: "Asia/Colombo"
});
let _date = new Date(curent_date);
```

Comment: The current time is UTC, however the open and close times are local, so you will have timezone offset issues unless you specify the timezone or offset to use for the times as well.

Comment: @RobG Hi I've updated the above question. I have mentioned how I'm getting the current time with the timezone. it's better if you can suggest a better way to get this.

Comment: That code is problematic and may produce an invalid date. What it's doing is generating a timestamp for Asia/Colombo that may or may not be parsed as a local date (it might result in an invalid date) and introduces issues with daylight saving that may be different between the location used (e.g. Asia/Colombo) and the local system. What you need is the offset or IANA representative location for the times.